# regex for all text beginning with "#" but not with #define

Tags: regex, lex

the regex i am using is for an implementation of preprocessor, in flex. 
This preprocessor is kindof simple. 
It obeys following rules:

1. the preprocessor directive starts with #define followed by identifier in capital letters
2. the use-case of preprocessor identifier begins with a `#` sign.

for example:

```
#define CONSTANT 100
//...
int x = #CONSTANT;
```

so first thing i did was

```
#define {
           //store the identifier following #define in a lookup table 
           //do the relevant error checking 
        }
NO_POUND_DEFINE {
                  //The string should begin with a '#' sign but not with `#define`
                  //check if the string following '#' is upper case or not
                  //if in upper case do the lookup otherwise throw an error
                }
```

Comment: What language? How about the `#define` in `match the #define`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^#([^d]|d[^e]|de[^f]|def[^i]|defi[^n]|defin[^e]).*` The string starts with a '#' not followed by a 'd' or followed by a 'd' but not followed by an 'e' etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regexp = /^((?!#define).)*$/;
```

Maybe you want to take a look at this: [regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: on lex version 2.5.4, it says unrecognized rule.

Comment: Yeah, Lex probably doesn't like Perl's rexexes for obvious performance reasons ;-)